# Magento 2 contribution automated tests

Tags: magento2, github, opensource

I've started to contribute on Magento Open Source project on Github.

I did my first commit and opened a pull request.

I added/replaced some lines of code in a JS file, trying to follow all the guide lines from Magento.

5 of 15 automated tests fail and watching into details (for example: Static Tests) I'm not able to find the reason why these tests fails...
[image]

What I see is all "green" and some tests skipped "grey" but nothing failed "red".
[image]

This is the PR link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/35468

Any comment will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an answer to my question, but re-running tests several times and they started to be successful...

This makes me think that probably, sometimes, if the test fails it is not our fault.

I hope someone in the future can better explain why and determine the cause of the failure.

Thanks